# Variadic arguments in cassandra query with gocql

Tags: go, cassandra, variadic-functions, gocql

I want to make a generic function for performing cassandra queries using the gocql client, something like :

```
queryExec("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(?,?,?,?)", userId, emailId, mobileNo, gender)

func queryExec(query string, args ...interface{}) err{
err := session.query(query, args).Exec()
return err
```

}

but when I pass it multiple argument values, it gives me the following error :

```
gocql : expected 4 values send got 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
err := session.query(query, args...).Exec()
```

Without the ellipsis, `query` receives a slice containing all the args.